# FFmpeg/avconv module not installed

Tags: javascript

I'm making a discord.js v13 version bot
but, FFmpeg/avconv module not installed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhWS2.png)

Comment: Try `npm install ffmpeg-static --save`.

Comment: I installed it and got the bot running but I get an error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please refer to the article below

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see on the npm page of [avconv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/avconv) (if this is the module you are trying to use), you have to install it through `npm install avconv`. I don't think any npm package can be installed with `npm install author/package`.

Maybe you are trying to install with `@author/name`?